# how to hide hyphen in a gap before first character in text editor in .Net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, text-editor

I pressed some button on keyboard then in my current view has a hyphen in empty space in front of a first character in each line.

I really don't know what is this property?

how to hide them?

```
------------_appearanceOption.Brush = _brush;
------------_appearanceOption.Font = _batchHeaderFont;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is know as the "View White Space" feature, and can be toggled with the menu:

> Edit > Advanced > View White Space

or with keyboard shortcuts:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

That is `View White Space`

Try this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

or

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

or

```
Go to Edit -> Advanced -> and uncheck  "View Whitespace"
```

[image]